# How do I find and input a domain name in Raspberry Pi/Windows 10?

Tags: raspberry-pi4

I am trying to control my Raspberry Pi from my Windows 10 laptop. My Raspberry Pi needs my laptop's IP Address, my username on said laptop, a password, and a domain name. I have tried to find this information on my Windows Command Prompt and Raspberry Pi terminal, but the domain name keeps coming up as 'WORKGROUP.' I tried to put the domain name as WORKGROUP, or even the name of the laptop, but it still won't connect. I have also tried to ping my laptop from the Raspberry Pi monitor, the pinging was successful, but the two devices wouldn't connect even after I entered two different IP Addresses through Remmina on the Pi. I have a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B.

Answer (score 1):

Your laptop will not have a domain name, unless you bought it from a domain register, and assigned it to the public IP that is, or forwards to your laptop.

If you are trying to connect to the laptop from the raspberry pi over ssh on the same network, you will only need your laptop username, password, and local IP address. You can find the local IP address of you laptop by typing into the command prompt

```
ipconfig
```

Then, look at IPv4 and you will find the local IP. In the raspberry pi console, type ssh (username)@(Ip_address)

If you are trying to connect to the raspberry pi from the laptop, the old way was to install a program like Putty, and put in the local IP of the raspberry pi, and username and control it that way. Windows now has an SSH service built in, and you can do this from powershell.

Go to manage optional features, and add OpenSSH Client (May need to reboot)

Then, open PowerShell and type ssh (username_of_pi)@(IP_of_pi)

Usually the default username of the raspberry pi is "pi" and the password is "raspberry"